# how to find smallest integer which is multiple of given number and has only digits 0 and 9

Tags: number-theory

More Precisely I am trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/special-multiple/problem problem. I know its programming solution to generate binary strings and check that combination works or not. But I want to know if some mathematical solution exists which can solve this problem. without exhaustively checking all the possibilities

Comment: Hint:  if $\gcd(n,10)=1$ then $n\,|\,10^{\varphi(n)}-1$.

Comment: @lulu I suspect that your hint only gives existence, but not "smallest integer".

Comment: @CalvinLin  Oh, you are right.  Missed that condition.

Comment: My belief is that we essentially have to test out all cases. We could simplify the work some by calculating $10^i \pmod{N}$, but it's essentially writing a program to check all terms (and the math theory tells us that a correctly run program will eventually terminate)

Comment: The problem using only $0$ and $1$ is clearly related.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388165/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-give).

Comment: @lulu Essentially the problem using $0$ and $1$ is equivalent.  If $n$ is coprime to $3$, $n \mid 9 y$ iff $n \mid y$.  If $n$ is divisible by $3$ but not $9$, $n \mid  9 y$ iff $n/3 \mid 3 y$ iff $n/3 \mid y$.  If $n$ is divisible by $9$, $n \mid 9 y$ iff $n/9 \mid y$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Ah, yes.  Good point.