# Prove that, given any positive integer n, some multiple of it must be of the form 99...900...0

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that, given any positive integer n, some multiple of it must be of the form 99...900...0
Give me a hand, please.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164986/smallest-multiple-whose-digits-are-only-ones-and-zeros

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use Dirichlet pigeonhole principle to show that some two numbers of the form 999...99 
(all nines) give the same remainder when divided by n.

Answer (score 1):

If $n\in\mathbb N$, then $n=2^k5^\ell z$, where $z$ not divisible by $2$ or $5$. But $z$ divides $10^{z-1}-1$, and hence
$n$ divides $10^{\max{k,\ell}}(10^{z-1}-1)$.